# Can I use the spring context in javax websocket?

Tags: spring, spring-security, websocket, spring-websocket

I am trying to implement one javax.websocket in application and would like to use the spring context to interact with my rest of the application.
Is it possible anyway?
I have tried by simple auto wire of context but of no help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't provide enough details to be sure but using the [WebApplicationContextUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/WebApplicationContextUtils.html) class could give you access to your Spring context. You can use beans defined in your context but you can't use all of Spring's capabilities since you are outside of the Spring container.

If you want full Spring capabilities you might flip the problem on its head. Instead of accessing Spring from your websocket endpoint, how about integrating the websocket endpoint into Spring? See here for a basic example: [Using websockets in Java using Spring 4.](http://syntx.io/using-websockets-in-java-using-spring-4/)

Comment: Thanks Bogdan the thing is I have one Websocket created uisng javax API of tomcat and not using the spring websocket now I have moved that code to my spring aaplication but I am not able to get there the Spring application context to access other API's through application context inot the Websocket code.

Comment: @BhaskarPatle: if you created a websocket handler in Spring then that handler is just another Spring bean. This means you are *inside* the Spring context so you can inject other beans into it.